# Unexpected exit when <c-x><c-o> in Python file

Tags: autocompletion

Vim quits abruptly whenever I try to use omni-completion `<c-x><c-o>` in a Python file. This doesn't happen with other filetypes. `:echo &omnifunc` produces `pythoncomplete#Complete`.

How can I troubleshoot this?

**Update.** A possible clue. When I do `:python` in Vim (e.g. per [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2086309/1493867)), then Vim quits in the same way.

Comment: `pythoncomplete#Complete` actually uses `python` to preform the completions.  The function is inside `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim` and at the end it calls `execute "python vimcomplete('" . cword . "', '" . a:base . "')"`.  Can you actually call `python` from your vim?  e.g. `:python print "yay!"`  (also test `:python print("yay")`, the python3 syntax.

Comment: @grochmal My edit and your comment must have crossed. The answer is "no" (see update). What to do now?

Comment: hmmm... what about `vim -u NONE -c 'so $VIMRUNTIME/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim' -c 'python vimcomplete("de", "")' -c 'echo g:pythoncomplete_completions'` (this should print a `[]` in the Vim command line when it opens)

Comment: @grochmal I get a series of `"c" [New File]` and `'so [New File]` etc and finally `"g:pythoncomplete_completions'"`

Comment: You got the quoting wrong, `-c` is a way to pass normal mode commands to Vim when it starts.  Be very careful with the quotes.  The interchange between single and double quotes in the command is also important.

Comment: @grochmal My mistake. I didn't know that command was for the terminal, not the vim command line as earlier. Anyway, I know what the problem is now. My Windows vim is not compiled with `+python`. Does that mean no hope for me?

Comment: install Vim from [here](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer) and don't forget to install python as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is too long for a comment.  Also, I misunderstood one of the comments at first and it resulted in the unnecessary long list of comments.

If your Vim does not support `python` you cannot perform `python` completion.  This is because the script that performs python completion relies on python.  The code is in `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim` and looks as follows:

```
function! pythoncomplete#Complete(findstart, base)
    ...
        endwhile
        execute "python vimcomplete('" . cword . "', '" . a:base . "')"
        return g:pythoncomplete_completions
    endif
endfunction
```

That `execute` in there calls `:python` and will fail if your Vim install has no python support.  To check for python support you can do either:

```
:echo has('python')
```

Or check the output of `vim --version` for `+python` (or `+python3` which will work as well since there is a `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/python3complete.vim` which uses python3).

---

After searching a little here on stack exchange I found that on MS Windows Vim often comes without `python` support.  But have faith, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718122/how-to-enable-python-support-in-gvim-on-windows) on stack overflow to find how to enable `python` on MS Windows.

In summary, if you install `python` on MS Windows with the default Windows installer (not the ActivePython) the Vim installer will be capable of finding the python `.dll`s.

Also, there is the classic catch that both Vim and python must be binaries of the same architecture.  i.e. you must make sure that both are either `i386` (32bit) or `x86_64` (64bit) binaries.  On MS Windows it should be easy to check based on the directory they're in: `Program Files (x86)` or `Program Files`.

References:

- [How to enable Python support in gVim on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718122/how-to-enable-python-support-in-gvim-on-windows)